# Windows message pump

Tags: operating-system, architecture

This is just a technical question to improve my understanding of OS architecture.

I understand when the Application.Run() method is executed, a new form with its message pump is created. From MSDN and other online articles, I understand its thread safe nature and even understand that the Windows OS components like HAL layer, core OS services and applications on the top of the hierarchy all communicate between one another using messaging too.

Is this custom only to Windows or does this happen in the Linux environment too?

Can this be thought of as a semaphore? Or does the definition and context of a semaphore only make sense in a multi-threaded environment?

Please advice.

Thanks,

Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways how processes can communicate, together called IPC - inter-process communication. From historical reasons, in UNIX-like systems use other mechanisms for communicating between processes than the message loop. UNIX processes are usually communicating through pipes (one can think about them as temporary files which can be only written in one process and read in another one), signals (code preempting the actual execution of some process) or process return values (similar to function returning). There are many other ways how to communicate (sockets, shared memory, files) but these are the most usual.

As for the semaphores: I am not sure how should these be related to message passing, semaphores objects designed for allowing programmers to create critical sections of code. Because in UNIX can be semaphore shared even between different processes (not only different threads in one process), they make sense in any multi-process OS (which is almost every today's OS), even with no threading support.

Well, semaphores can be used even with fibrils - userspace threads which are not preempted by exhausting their time quantum, as threads do, but which yield control to another fibril manually (for example when the fibril is about to begin a long blocking operation such as reading data from harddisk, it may request the data and instead of blocking switch to another fibril which wants CPU).

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems have the message queues:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
ssize_t msgrcv(int msqid, void *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp, int msgflg);
```

which are much less used than Windows messages but operate in a very similar fashion. Also a very similar concept, the [Go language](http://golang.org/) nicely implements the CSV ([communicating sequential processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes)), which is an excellent multitasking paradigm, because does not suffer from exponential complexity growth. I would recommend Unix system programmers to use message queues more.

Windows messages are also somewhat similar to Unix signals, but Unix signals (usually) don't have arguments, are very limited in number (often only 32, compared to thousands of Windows messages) and the signal handlers have to execute in a weird suspended environment, which makes them much less practical. Nonetheless, signals are much more popular in Unix programming than message queues.

### Regarding semaphores

Rather than using semaphores (which have an attached counter), you should first try to use mutexes, which are more lightweight and usable for synchronizing threads inside the same process.